# Python Selenium Selecting Files from File System

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select files from the file system to add to the field which is not a form field, I tried using "send_keys" but didn't work.

Also, is there any way to handle os pop up's like "renaming a file in the download dialog box before saving it"?

Here's the link, please have a look: https://pdfcandy.com/jpg-to-pdf.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="file"]')


element.send_keys(r"<path>\testupload.jpg")
```

It already has input elemnt

Comment: apologize I'm kinda new to these sort of things, can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: First upload the file and then inspect the element and see if an input element is there

Comment: yeah, when I upload the files it creates multiple 'img' tags. should I inject these 'img' tags using your solution ?

Comment: Could you provide the site link

Comment: @Sean it already have inut element updated the answer just send file path to that element